# How to translated preposition + ing in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How to translate sentences like "before doing X" in Latin since ante requires an accusative?

Comment: you could use a gerund?

Comment: Not sure if this is correct

Comment: Really needs more specificity. Even a single English example would be helpful.

Comment: related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14987/how-to-translate-a-sentence-where-gerunds-are-present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ante quam* (or one word *antequam*), tense and mood vary (Lewis & Short s.v. *ante* II.b.2.). *Ante quam ad sententiam redeo, de me pauca dicam*, Cic. Cat. 4, 20, etc. etc.